# Bitrix добавить колонку в таблицу БД

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем привет. Есть таблица, а в ней есть колонки и значения.

Как добавить колонку в список таблиц в bitrix? Пример на картинке. Там есть другие колонки, но нужной мне колонки в левом списке колонок нет. Мне нужно добавить туда еще одну колонку, которая уже создана в базе данных и имеет значение. Гуглил, но ничего не нашел.

ПС. Вы можете подумать что я спрашиваю как "перетащить колонку из левой в правую"  - нет, это я знаю. Вопрос в том, как именно добавить в список колонок другую.

Как быть, в чем решение, в какую сторону и что гуглить ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Нашел Проблема Решается если создать пользовательское свойство, Настройки => Список Пользователей.

Comment: Самый лучший форумчанин. Сам спросил, сам ответил!) Лайк